# Get value of parameter from text file using sed

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I am trying to extract the value of a parameter from the text file.

Below is my text file with uri_param as parameter.

```
application.txt
---------------
uri_param=frontier://tenant=stripe;env=qa;svc=new-service@stripe-ftr-qa.stripe.nxz.com:80

command:
--------
egrep ^uri_param application.txt | sed -e 's/.*=//'
```

I am expecting the strign after first `=` as output i.e. `frontier://tenant=stripe;env=qa;svc=new-service@stripe-ftr-qa.stripe.nxz.com:80`, but the output I am getting is `new-service@stripe-ftr-qa.stripe.nxz.com:80`.

How can I fix this? What I found till now is .* in sed is greedy and it will match the longest string after `=`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sed -r 's/^[_0-9a-zA-Z]+=//g' File_Name
```

Comment: using this with small modification:
sed -e 's/[._0-9a-zA-Z]*=//'

Comment: This works if we dont have any space between key and value in txt file, if there are spaces anishsane's answer i.e. s/[^=]*=// works perfectly

Answer (score 3):

```
sed -n '/^uri_param=/ {s///p;q;}' YourFile
```

- extract only the first occurance of the uri_param, remove this uri_param= (replace by nothing) and print it then quit.
- OK for small and medium file (a grep is faster enough on a big file like 100 Mb)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this way

```
sed -r s'/[^=]+.(.*)/\1/g' File_Name
```

Comment: don't need a group to extract, just replace the begin with nothing

Answer (score 1):

We can filter it in the `grep` part:

```
grep -o "^uri_param=.*:[0-9]\{1,\}" infile|sed -e "s/^uri_param=//"
```

Or use a more flexible tool like `gawk`:

```
gawk 'match($0, "^uri_param=(.*:[0-9]+)", r){print r[1]}' infile
```

NOTE: If your `url` doesn't finish allways with the port number the `pattern` should be adjusted.